# Ant .NET library documentation? (setting console logger parameters)

Tags: java, c++, ant, msbuild

I'm building a project that uses a C++ backend for processing speed and a Java UI, and building the backend binaries with an Ant task called "msbuild" inside the Apache .NET Ant library:

http://ant.apache.org/antlibs/dotnet/

But I can't seem to find any documentation for the elements the "msbuild" task supports. I'd like to experiment with different console logger parameters.

Is there some documentation out there that I just can't find readily? Or is there a way to determine the properties and nested elements the "msbuild" task supports without reading documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably just a wrapper for Msbuild.exe.  Which comes with each version of the framework.

MSBuild Command Line Reference

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms164311%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

The screen shots (from your link) show "2.0", which means it is probably a wrapper for:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\msbuild.exe

..............

When you have a custom task that wraps the msbuild.exe.....then hopefully you can find the source code for that custom task.
That will tell the story on what the implementer (of the custom task) actually "coded up".

**What I have found with custom-tasks is that the implementor(s) will put in most/some of the overall properties, but not all of them.**

Which (if you can get hold of the original source), you can get the code and add extra properties as you need.

..............

If you cannot get the source code.........then use a reflector (I like ILSpy) to look at the properties that are settable on your task.  (or a java equivalent if your custom task is written in java)

......
Remember, at the end of the day, a custom task is just a super-fancy wrapper for the command line.
You set properties on the custom task, and the code of the task puts it into command line form.
Take that with a grain of salt, but that is usually what a command-line tool wrapper does.
I haven't seen the original source code, but I'd strongly guess that is what is going on.

EDIT:

Get the source code:

current location:

http://www.gtlib.gatech.edu/pub/apache//ant/antlibs/dotnet/source/apache-ant-dotnet-1.1-src.zip

or from here:

http://ant.apache.org/antlibs/srcdownload.cgi

Figure out what the source code is doing.

```
/*
 *  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
 *  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
 *  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
 *  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
 *  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 *  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 *  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 *  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 *  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 *  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 *  limitations under the License.
 *
 */

package org.apache.ant.dotnet.build;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.ant.dotnet.util.CollectionUtils;

import org.w3c.dom.DocumentFragment;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

/**
 * Runs a MSBuild build process.
 */
public class MSBuildTask extends AbstractBuildTask {

    private static final String TARGET = "generated-by-ant";
    private static final String ROOT = "Project";
    private static final String MSBUILD_NS =
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003";

    public MSBuildTask() {
        super();
    }

    protected String getExecutable() {
        return "MSBuild.exe";
    }

    protected String[] getBuildfileArguments(File buildFile) {
        if (buildFile != null) {
            return new String[] {
                buildFile.getAbsolutePath()
            };
        } else {
            return new String[0];
        }
    }

    protected String[] getTargetArguments(List targets) {
        if (targets.size() > 0) {
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("/target:");
            sb.append(CollectionUtils.flattenToString(targets, ";"));
            return new String[]{sb.toString()};
        } else {
            return new String[0];
        }
    }

    protected String[] getPropertyArguments(List properties) {
        if (properties.size() > 0) {
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("/property:");
            sb.append(CollectionUtils.flattenToString(properties, ";"));
            return new String[]{sb.toString()};
        } else {
            return new String[0];
        }
    }

    /**
     * Turn the DocumentFragment into a DOM tree suitable as a build
     * file when serialized.
     *
     * <p>If we have exactly one <Project> child, return that.
     * Otherwise if we have only <Task> children, wrap them into a
     * <Target> which in turn gets wrapped into a <Project>.
     * Otherwise, fail.</p>
     */
    protected Element makeTree(DocumentFragment f) {
        NodeList nl = f.getChildNodes();
        if (nl.getLength() == 1 
            && nl.item(0).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE
            && nl.item(0).getNodeName().equals(ROOT)) {
            return (Element) nl.item(0);
        } else {
            Element p = f.getOwnerDocument().createElementNS(MSBUILD_NS,
                                 ROOT);
            p.setAttribute("DefaultTargets", TARGET);

            Element t = f.getOwnerDocument().createElementNS(MSBUILD_NS,
                                 "Target");
            t.setAttribute("Name", TARGET);

            p.appendChild(t);
            t.appendChild(f);
            return p;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been clearer. I've got elements and properties on that msbuild task like "build" "target" and "property" which translate into arguments for the msbuild executable. I like the more human-readable nature of this task, but I can't find any documentation about what additional properties/nested elements it supports and I'd like to specify things like processor count and squelch logging.

Comment: I made an edit.  Who downvoted me?  Geeze, you try to help people..and I get not upvoting me, but its not like I didn't try to help the OP.

Comment: Sorry, that was me. I've since fixed it, thanks for putting in the effort, but it looks like if I want to have it trip extra switches I'll have to code that support in on my own.

Comment: Rule of Thumb.  The source-code doesn't lie.  Which is why I try to find it and prefer open-source projects.  Yes, if you want super-easy to set properties, you'll probably end up enhancing the code.  I would inherit from the above class, and make my own version.  But that's me.